# Gstreamer, Raspberry Pi, and Android. How to get streaming video?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I've been working for 2 solid days on trying to get Gstreamer on a pi to output video on an android device. I can do the pi > Mac, but cannot get the android Gstreamer SDK tutorial 3 to stream video from my raspberry pi.

I'm currently working withthe Android "tutorial 3" from the gstreamer SDK.
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+3%3A+Video

Right now I set the pi with the host set to the IP of the pi>

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 360 -w 640 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.155 port=5000
```

The in the gstreamer tutorial i'm setting the gst_parse_launch>

```
udpsrc port=5000 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, sprop-parameter-sets=\\\"J2QAFKwrQLj/LwDxImo\\\\=\\\\,KO4fLA\\\\=\\\\=\\\"\", payload=96\" ! rtph264depay  ! queue ! sync=false
```

within the android app, i'm getting "unable to build pipeline no element udpsrc"

I feel i'm missing a "plugin" but i'm unsure what to do as I've tried many variations.

Comment: What does your Android.mk file look like?  Does it have a line starting with GSTREAMER_PLUGINS and does that line either contain udp or GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET (see http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development)

Comment: You nailed it! That was the connection I was missing. The error is no more. I now get: ` Error received from element udpsrc0: Could not open resource for reading.` I suspect this has to do with the server side implementation of gstreamer. I'm unsure if i'm using udpsink correctly when executing on the pi. The string is included in the question.

Comment: Do an adb logcat on the android device and look for errors.  Also ensure that you have INTERNET permission in your android manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration of the plugins is done in your Android.mk file.  Make sure that the line starting with `GSTREAMER_PLUGINS` contains either

```
udp
```

or

```
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET
```

GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET is a macro that specifies lots of plugins including udp.  See [gstreamer's Android installation guide](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development)